# How to send data to javascript while executing code

Tags: javascript, flask

I have a web app with Flask, what i can do is get data from a form in html so my code can do the stuff with that data, but, when the data is being processed i want to show the results while executing the code like sending the data to the template without refreshing.

I searched about doing this stuff with JS but those examples didn´t help me a lot.

For Ex:

```
@app.route('/homeip', methods=['GET','POST'])
def homeip():
     data = []
     c = 0
     while c < len(total_data):
          ---stuff---
          return render_template('homeip.html', result=data)
```

When my code goes to the return statement sends the data to the template with render_template but ultil my code goes to the return statement i want updates in the page in the "do stuff" section.

Comment: What you are asking doesn't fit in the HTTP request-response model.

Comment: Use websocket to send partial results

Comment: or alternatively "server sent events"